# In the remote data access code for Pandas tutorial, what does "F" mean?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

```
In [12]: import pandas_datareader.data as web

In [13]: import datetime

In [14]: start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)

In [15]: end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)

In [16]: f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo-dividends', start, end)
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off filing an issue on github to add an explanation. Also, I don't see actual API docs in the documentation.

Comment: This is not a Pandas tutorial. pandas_datareader is a totally separate project.

Comment: All that being said, you should now be able to select my answer.

Comment: Yes, I shall file an issue on GitHub for it. Thanks anyway for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation is sadly lacking in the generated docs for [`pandas_datareader`](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). However, the functions themselves are pretty well documented in the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader). Looking at the source for [`DataReader`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/cfb15f3c822444c61c880259959a6621cfed3dcb/pandas_datareader/data.py#L213), the first parameter is [`name`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/cfb15f3c822444c61c880259959a6621cfed3dcb/pandas_datareader/data.py#L223):

> the name of the dataset. Some data sources (google, fred) will accept a list of names.

This is not informative, but digging deeper, into the classes of objects that `DataReader` actually returns, like [`YahooDailyReader`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/cfb15f3c822444c61c880259959a6621cfed3dcb/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py#L10), and how they are constructed, the first parameter is the [stock symbol or symbols](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/cfb15f3c822444c61c880259959a6621cfed3dcb/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py#L19):

> Single stock symbol (ticker), array-like object of symbols or DataFrame with index containing stock symbols.

In this case, `'F'` is the symbol for [Ford](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/F?p=F). With the yahoo data source, you have the option of supplying a single string or an iterable of strings to get multiple outputs at once.